# Input Type="Range" not getting refreshed in PhoneGap IOS application

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I am developing iPhone Application in Phone Gap IOS, in this I am creating an audio bar which will contain a slider to show the progress of audio running and through this I can make the audio backward and forward also and there is one label that will show the Elapsed time.

I am using HTML5 input Type="range" as a slider and JQuery Mobile is implemented in my application.

The issue I am facing is that when the music play the handle of the slider does not progress with the music it remain at the start of slider, after doing some research I come to know that the slider is not getting refreshed that why the position is not getting changed, for this I wrote the following code of line  to refresh the slider.

```
$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider("refresh");
```

But it give me the following error:

> Type Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider("refresh")')

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this, the two methods are not chainable with each other:

```
$("input[type='range']").val("60");
$("input[type='range']").slider("refresh");
```

Comment: Thanks Raminson for your reply, actually i have implemented this code before also but it also give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The slider you want to refresh can be simply not initialized yet if you run this code before your page was initialized. Please try to initialize it before you refresh it.

Try:

```
$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider();
```